# Tikz: positioning of plot within node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, plot

I would like to use \begin{axis} and \addplot within a node, as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5,yscale=0.5]
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}
}
\node [rectangle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {
\begin{axis}[height=3cm,width=5cm]
\addplot {gauss(0,0.5)};
\end{axis}
};

\node [rectangle, draw] (b) at (5,-2) {Test};

\draw [<->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The rectangle unfortunately does not surround the plot. How can that be fixed?

What is the correct way to include a plot in a node?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome. An `axis` *is* a node. What you are trying to do is to nest `tikzpicture`s, which is to be avoided. If you only want to add a frame around the `axis` node, just add `\draw (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);` after `\end{axis}` before `\end{tikzpicture}`. (There are many other possibilities.)

Comment: I would say the correct way is to *not* place the `axis` in a node. If you want the `axis` at a specific location, and/or refer to its anchors, use `\begin{axis}[at={(x,y)}, name=foo, ...]` (the default anchor is `south west`, so the bottom left corner of the axis is placed at `(x,y)`). With `name=foo` you can use e.g. `(foo)` or `(foo.north)` as a coordinate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The fact that an axis is simply a node makes things more logical in my head. I have updated my example as follows:

\begin{tikzpicture}         
\begin{axis}[name=a,width=4cm,at={(0,0)}]
\addplot {gauss(0,0.5)};
\end{axis}

\node [rectangle,draw,name=b] at (5,-3) {XYZ};

\begin{axis}[name=c,width=4cm,at={(7,0)}]
\addplot {gauss(3,1)};
\end{axis}

\draw [<->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

Strangely the arrow is not in the right place, connecting a with b. Do you see why this is?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));}]
\begin{axis}[name=a,width=4cm] 
\addplot[domain=-3:3] {gauss(x,0,0.5)}; 
\end{axis} 
\node [rectangle,draw,name=b] at (5,-3) {XYZ}; 
\begin{axis}[name=c,width=4cm,xshift=7cm] 
\addplot[domain=-3:3] {gauss(x,3,1)}; 
\end{axis} 
\draw [<->] (a) -- (b); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

This is more to familiarize you with the format. If you want to respond to a comment, then you need to address the user you want to address. So in your above comment you should have added @TorbjørnT. Also you should edit your question instead of adding code pieces in the comments. In any case, the following works. Your approach suffered from spurious spaces in the definition of the Gaussian, and `declare function` is arguably easier to deal with anyway (but you could just have removed the spaces).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=1/(\z*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\y)^2)/(2*\z^2));}]
\begin{axis}[name=a,width=4cm] 
\addplot[domain=-3:3] {gauss(x,0,0.5)}; 
\end{axis} 
\node [rectangle,draw,name=b] at (5,-3) {XYZ}; 
\begin{axis}[name=c,width=4cm,xshift=7cm] 
\addplot[domain=-3:3] {gauss(x,3,1)}; 
\end{axis} 
\draw [<->] (a) -- (b); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]